# Get html output from python code

Tags: python, html

I have dictionary and would like to produce html page where will be drawn simple html table with keys and values. How it can be done from python code?

Comment: Umm... print HTML in your Python code, maybe?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information.  How are you outputting this HTML; are you using a template library like Genshi?  How are you producing a table from a dictionary?  Is each item in the dict a list of values for that column?

Comment: I don't use any template libraries and if you can advice something to have output then it would be good. Html table is simple. Two columns where first are the keys and second their corresponding values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
output = "<html><body><table>"
for key in your_dict:
  output += "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>" % (key, your_dict[key])
output += "</table></body></html>
print output
```

Comment: maybe you meant 'for key, value in your_dict:' ;-)

Comment: Remember to HTML-escape any text you concatenate into HTML, or you'll have bugs and cross-site-scripting security holes.

Comment: Fixed the value issue, thanks jbochi. Regarding HTML escaping I could have added cgi.escape(...) but I'll leave it simple.

Comment: Thank you rui. Formatting html strings is enough for simple html table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template engine like [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/). A list of engines for templating is available [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating).

Answer (score 1):

You maybe interested by markup see http://markup.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider using [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) template library.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the numerous template engines, you might consider using Python's built in [Template.](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) It will give you basic templating functionality without needing to learn (or choose) a template library.